# Command "react-native" can not run after installed react-native-drawer

Tags: react-native

I inited React native project by:

react-native init MyShop
In MyShop folder, I install "[react-native-drawer](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer)":

npm install --save react-native-drawer
After install, I run project by:

react-native run-android
And get error "Command run-android unrecognized. Make sure that you have run npm install and that you are inside a react-native project."
I checked react-native by command line

react-native -v
And get info:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory
It seems react-native lib has been removed after installed react-native-drawer.
My npm version:

E:\2.Projects\My\MyShop>npm -v
5.0.4
My node version:

E:\2.Projects\My\MyShop>node -v
v8.1.2
Please help me re-procedure and fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling react native's cli?

Comment: I tried reinstalling react-native-cli but I'm not success.

Answer (score 1):

I found out solution for this issue!
I update npm to latest version: 5.1.0.
Uninstall react-native-cli:

> npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

Next, reinstall react-native-cli:

> npm install -g react-native-cli

My issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Install react-native without -cli

> npm install -g react-native

It will fix the issue......Hopefully....coz

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.